# Loops, maybe? Using values in one row to set values in another

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range A1:J3. I want to set a value in A3:J3 if the corresponding cell in A1:J1 is not empty.

I essentially want it to do this: If (row 1, col i) is not empty, then set value of (row 3, col i) to "8"

So basically the finished product would look like this.
[image: Example 1]

I'm fairly inexperienced with complex scripting and I wasn't sure if this was a loop or what.

Comment: You could just use a formula in the third row. If it must be a script, yes, you would loop. Review Apps Script documentation and "best practices" - you can find information to get you started there. When you have a specific programming issue, please edit your question to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

A3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:J1),,8))
```